# Переключение фрагментов в Activity

Tags: android

В MainActivity, при выборе определённого меню (из NavigationView), подгружаются определённые табы с фрагментами. (ManagerFragment и  PlanFragment)

При переключении в меню на пункт 2 (tenders, см. Listener)
Меняются только имена табов, без изменения фрагмента.
Подскажите, в каком направлении копать.(Жизненный цикл фрагмента?)
Изначально хотел реализовать всё это через дополнительные Activity, но хочется попробовать сделать всё в одном Activity.

***MainActivity:***

```
  package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.adapter.TabsFragmentAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.activity_main;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(LAYOUT);


        setupToolBar();
        setupNavigationView();
        setupPlanTabs();


    }

    private void setupToolBar() {


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    }

    private void setupNavigationView() {

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle togle =
                new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this,
                        drawerLayout,
                        toolbar,
                        R.string.view_navigation_open,
                        R.string.view_navigation_close);

//     drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(togle);

        togle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                switch (item.getItemId()) {


                    case R.id.plan:
                        setupPlanTabs();
                        break;

                    case R.id.tenders:
                        setupTendersTabs();
                        break;


                    case R.id.shipments:
                        setupShipmentsTabs();
                        break;


                }


                return true;
            }
        });


    }


    private void setupPlanTabs() {


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), true, false, false);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    private void setupTendersTabs() {


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), false, true, false);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    private void setupShipmentsTabs() {


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), false, false, true);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


}
```

***TabFragmentAdapter:***

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.AbstractTabFragment;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTenders.InWorkTendersFragment;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTenders.StatTendersFragment;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTheSale.ManagersFragment;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTheSale.PlanFragment;


public class TabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {




    //for use strings
    private Context context;
    private Map<Integer, AbstractTabFragment> tabs;

    private boolean isTheSale;
    private boolean isTenders;
    private boolean isShipments;


    public TabsFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, boolean isTheSale, boolean isTenders, boolean isShipments) {
        super(fm);
        this.isTheSale = isTheSale;
        this.isTenders = isTenders;
        this.isShipments = isShipments;
        this.context = context;

        initTabs();

    }

    public TabsFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        this.context = context;


        initTabs();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    private void initTabs() {

        tabs = new HashMap<>();

        if (isTheSale) {
            tabs.put(0, PlanFragment.getInstance(context));
            tabs.put(1, ManagersFragment.getInstance(context));
        }

        else if (isTenders) {


            tabs.put(0, InWorkTendersFragment.getInstance(context));
            tabs.put(1, StatTendersFragment.getInstance(context));

        }

        else  if (isShipments){

        }

    }
}
```

**AbstractTabFragment**

```
    package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;

public class AbstractTabFragment extends Fragment {


    private String title;
    protected Context context;
    protected View view;


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {

        this.context=context;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

**ManagerFragment**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTheSale;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.R;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.AbstractTabFragment;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ManagersFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {


    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_managers;


    public static ManagersFragment getInstance(Context context){

        ManagersFragment fragment = new ManagersFragment();
        fragment.setContext(context);
        fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tab_managers_fragment));

        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**PlanFragment**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTheSale;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.R;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.AbstractTabFragment;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class PlanFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_plan;





    public static PlanFragment getInstance(Context context) {


/*        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);*/


        PlanFragment fragment = new PlanFragment();
        fragment.setContext(context);
        fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tab_plan_stat_fragment));

        return fragment;


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        return view;
    }








}
```

**InWorkTendersFragment**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTenders;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.R;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.AbstractTabFragment;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class InWorkTendersFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {


    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_in_work_tenders;


    public static InWorkTendersFragment getInstance(Context context) {


        InWorkTendersFragment fragment = new InWorkTendersFragment();
        fragment.setContext(context);
        fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tab_tenders_in_work_fragment));


        return fragment;


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        view =  inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

**StatTendersFragment**

```
package ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.fragmentsTenders;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.R;
import ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.AbstractTabFragment;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */


public class StatTendersFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {


    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_stat_tenders;




    public static StatTendersFragment getInstance(Context context) {


        StatTendersFragment fragment = new StatTendersFragment();
        fragment.setContext(context);
        fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tab_tenders_stat_fragment));

        return fragment;


    }






    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       view =  inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        return view;



    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы при каждом нажатии на пункт меню пересоздаёте и переназначаете адаптер для ViewPager. Так не надо делать. Адаптер надо создать и назначить лишь один раз, при создании активити.

При нажатии же на пункт меню вам надо лишь изменить состояние ViewPager через его адаптер. В простейшем случае лишь указать какой из фрагментов ему отобразить. Что-то типа `pager.setCurrentItem(1);` (меняя `1` на нужное значение).

Comment: В моём случае в каждом пункте меню должно быть по 2 таба. Я правильно понимаю, что в этом случае у меня будет 3 фрагмента, и в каждом по 2 для табов?

Comment: Я смутно представляю что вам надо. 3 таба сверху и в каждом 2 таба чуть ниже?...

Comment: вот тут описал подробнее
<http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535235/tabview-%D0%B8-viewpager-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0?lq=1>