# Реализация табов в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

По логике приложения, есть NavigationView с 3-мя пунктами меню. При нажатии на пункт "продажи",  должен открываться  новый фрагмент с 2-мя табами, которые в свою очередь подгружают по 1-му определённому фрагменту. Такая же история с остальными пунктами меню, но, естественно, табы + фрагменты табов нужно загружать другие.

**NavigationView:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Выбранный фрагмент и его табы:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**XML-разметка к MainActivity выглядит вот так:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhitePrimary"
    >


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"



                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight = "6dp"

                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"


            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>





    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"

    />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Пока что реализовано  одно Activity и его табы.
В самом MainActivity идёт инициализация ToolBar, NavigationView, ViewPager, TabLayout, так же создаётся экземпляр адаптера, который создаёт экземпляры фрагментов для табов.

**Как правильно реализовать данные функции с помощью фрагментов?
Или же лучше использовать обычные Activity с отдельными адаптерами и т.д.?**

Comment: Как сделал - я.
 Есть MenuActivity - тут сделан Toolbar and NavigationDrawer.
Далее есть Fragment GeneralFragment - В нем есть viewPager and Tabs.
А в ViewPager два Fragment

Comment: @ЕвгенийСуетин Я немного некорректно задал вопрос. Исправил тему.
Вы в Вашем примере использовали FrameLayout, что ли?
Сможете скинуть пример реализации Вашей конструкции?

Comment: да, конечно, давайте напишу сюда в ответ. только немного позже, так как сейчас немного занят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем, в начале я сделал MenuActivity через шаблоны от google, там есть drawer и content(RelativLayout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kilogramm.getberry.activity.MenuActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_menu">

</RelativeLayout>
```

в этот content_frame я буду вставлять фрагменты меню. Один из таких являтся HomeFragment c таким layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/home_color"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/blur_transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

да тут не очень обязательно было использовать LinearLayout внутри CoordinatorLayout. Далее как мы видим есть viewPager и tabs. Внутри viewPager него у меня два фрагменты frmnt1 и frgmnt2:

frgmnt1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_color"
                app:layout_anchor = "@+id/listView"
                app:layout_behavior= "com.kilogramm.getberry.tools.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
                app:layout_anchorGravity = "bottom|end"
                app:fabSize="normal"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

и собственно эту же xml я использую и для frgmnt2. Думаю реализацию кода приводить не стоит. Там все не так сложно.

Comment: спасибо!) попробую реализовать)

Comment: @AlexBykov Рад был помочь)

Comment: Всё же при реализации возник вопрос) Как Вы инициализировали ViewPager и TabLayout во фрагменте? Я правильно понимаю, что в такой реализации каждый фрагмент, который загружается в contant_frame имеет собственный viewPager и tabLayout? (в моём случае ещё и toolBar.)
У меня возникают ошибки при установки адаптера для viewPager и установки tabLayout вместе с viewPager (якобы все экземпляры кидают nullPointer, судя по дебаггеру).